# When to use GetXXX() method and when a Getter property

Tags: c#, methods, properties

There are some `.NET` libraries which use methods  for accessing object data instead of getters i.e `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()`.

Also there are examples of accessing an stream by a property i.e `HttpResponse.OutputStream`.

My question is when to use which form of access and why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=917023f6-d5b7-41bb-bbc0-411a7d66cf3c) rule: [CA1024: Use properties where appropriate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182181.aspx).

Comment: That states that it's bad to have properties that return arrays.  Can anybody elaborate on *why* that's bad?

Comment: Because the contents of the array can be changed to any arbitary values by anyone who can get a reference to it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Comment: If you return an array from a property, you are really returning a pointer to that array. This mean that you have suddenly made it so that other code can modify your array, even if you don't provide a setter method. So the contents of your array could be changed without you knowing it.

Comment: That `FxCop` rules are very good but I think one is missed. The number of times you need to access data. As we know network streams cannot seek back and I think that's why it make sense to only get the stream one time. I prefer throw an exception on subsequent calls to `GetSomeNetworkStream()`.

Answer (score 8):

Good question. Although a property is little more than syntax sugar for a pair of get/set methods, there two should be used in different times.

Generally, you should use a property-style getter when:

- The value to be returned represents field-like data (generally primitives/value types, but a reference to another domain object is also fine)
- The calculation, if any, to produce that value is relatively cheap/side-effect free
- Getting the same value twice will produce the same value given the same inputs

Generally, you should use a getter method when:

- The returned object is created for the purpose (e.g. factory methods)
- Evaluating the returned value requires side effects (e.g. touching a file system, database, or changing other values)
- Getting the return type twice will produce two distinct results (i.e. two Streams, db connections, etc).

In a sentence, if conceptually speaking the value needed is something the object HAS, use a property. If the value needed is the result of something the object DOES, use a method.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. [This](http://geekswithblogs.net/ewright/archive/2004/05/02/4537.aspx) article brings up a few good points. In general, I use methods when the computation is expensive and properties when computation is not expensive (i.e. a stored value is returned).

Answer (score 1):

My opinion which, I'm sure, will get to -10 real fast, is that you should only use properties for serialization.  In all other cases explicit method call is preferable because when you look at it, you know that a method with possible side effects is being invoked.

I guess the "correct" (tm) answer is that when all your method would do is return the value, it is ok to use getter/setter, but if there is any work to do, use a method.

Comment: Property Getters should **never ever** have side effects, if you have side effects I agree use a method instead.

Comment: A little simplistic. Properties are not so single-purpose; they allow you to make operations that require work look like simple assignments/retrievals, avoiding the morass of methods for some data and fields for others (and reducing the complexity of refactoring usages of a field that now takes internal work to handle).